# Relational and ER Modeling of a knowledge base

Tags: database, relational-database, erd

I'm involved in a project of creating a base of knowledge for human resources in projects. When doing the ER model of a little part of the problem a doubt assails me: which is the preferred way of modeling it, considering  efficiency, good design practices and database normalization. The application will be developed in .NET, but It could be queried using php, for example. We have 4 levels of entities which represents our knowledge base:

```
1   Supertopics
1.1   Topics
1.1.1   Subtopics
1.1.1.1   knowledge
```

I'm among two possible relational implementations:

**Option 1**- If using weak entities, each table will have a composed key: a unique Id plus the keys of the foreign tables of previous levels. It seems to be better to make complex reports with this model because of the replication of keys form all previous levels.

> - supertopic (IDSupertopic,...)
> - topic (IDSupertopic, IDTopic,...)
> - subtopic (IDSupertopic, IDTopic, IDSubtopic,...)
> - knowledge(IDSupertopic, IDTopic, IDSubtopic, IDKnowledge...)

**Option 2**- If using strong entities, each table will have a simple unique key, and a foreign key from the previous level object (table). It seems easier to manage this kind of model because of the simplification of table keys.

```
- supertopic (ConsecutiveKey,...)
- Topic (ConsecutiveKey, IDSupertopic, ...)
- subtopic(ConsecutiveKey, IDTopic...)
- knowledge(ConsecutiveKey, IDSubtopic...).
```

Can anyone give me some advise related with advantages and disadvantages of each possibility?

Comment: Your second option is better, but you'll also want to add non-unique indexes on the ID's of the 'parent' tables (e.g. in table knowledge, IDSubtopic will be a Foreign Key to table SubTopic and will also have an index on it to help queries).

Comment: Yes, table knowledge is defined as you says: ConsecutiveKey is the simple unique key for the table, and IDSubtopic is a foreign from Subtopic (non-unique). Indexes for foreign keys are generally defined. I also would like to know the reasons you have for choosing the second option.

Comment: The first option has redundant data. The Topic of a knowledge row is defined by the subtopic etc. Take that out and you have the second option.

Comment: Thanks Simon. You see "redundant data" in case 1, but that's the way the weak entities resolve to the relational model, and after resolving, the model is normalized. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think option 1 is fully normalised no. It has redundant data, that doesn't depend on the row itself but on data in other tables.

Comment: I have arrived to a conclusion after some reading about normalization: There are two possible scenarios: 1) One element of level N is associated with 1 and only 1 element N-1 level (Is the real case I'm solving). 2) One element of level N is related with more than 1 of level N.-1. Now, reading a bit about normalization: For the first scenario, option 1 is at least in 2NF, while option 2 is not. For the second scenario: option 1 is not a valid way of implementing the solution and option 2 would be the correct solution.